# How to use dependency injection in web api controller class for dbset objects

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I am use DI in my controller class as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1). The object I am passing with DI has to be used as dbset.

```
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly RPContext _context;
    private IResource _resource;

    public ValuesController(RPContext context, IResource resource)
    {
        _context = context;
        _resource = resource;
    }

    [HttpPost("{id}/{resourceName}")]
    public void Post([FromRoute] string id, [FromRoute] string resourceName, [FromBody] JObject Request)
    {
        _resource.Id = id;
        _resource.Name = resourceName;
        _resource.Location = (string)Request["location"];
        _context.Resources.Add(_resource);
        _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

I cannot use "_resource" in the above code with the Add method of Dbcontext object because it is an interface and not of class type. How else should I be doing this if I don't want to create new objects in my controller class?

Comment: This question contains a LOT of *things*: `1.` The controller inherit to `ControllerBase` instead of `Controller`. `2.` Using asynchronous task but returning `void`. `3.` Try to cast an interface to a class... I suggest you to read the documentation careful and follow step-by-step to understand how it works. Or just download the project and run (via the link you provide).

Comment: async was a copy-paste mistake made while adding code here from older version, removed it. When you create web api project through Visual Studio, it only inerits from controllerbase. Seems like Controller is for MVC views and models which I don't need.

Comment: @TânNguyễn About ControllerBase: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Indeed, we can use *almost everything* in Web API with a class that inherits from `Controller`, not just `ControllerBase` (I'm sure). And the question about the difference(s) may be in another post. I said that because: when I create new controller in my project (.net core 2.1), it inherits from `Controller`.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `IResource` is the *interface of a service*, not an *object* itself. So IResource isn't a new object. If you need a new object you can take a factory approach:

```
var resource = _resource.Create();
```

To add an entity to the context:

```
[HttpPost("{resourceName}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromRoute]string resourceName, [FromBody]JObject Request)
{
    var resource = new Data.Entities.Resource
    {
        Name = resourceName,
        Location = (string)Request["location"]
    };
    _context.Resources.Add(resource);
    _context.SaveChangesAsync();

     return CreatedAtRoute("Get", new { id = resource.Id }, resource.Id);
}
```

Where the result links to the created object.

I noticed that you've included an Id for this request. But it seems that a new resource is created, so I've omitted the Id because it is probably set in the database.